# Get the status returned from the process that just finished

Tags: bash

I have a process that just finished (it was written in C) so I return a number in main to tell the status. How can I get this value from the process that just finished in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `echo $?` directly after you run your command:

```
 $ ./myprogram
 $ echo $?
```

If you are trying to base a decision on the success of your command, you can use `&&`:

```
 $ ./myprogram && echo success
```

if you are trying to base a decision on the failure of your command, you can use `||`:

```
 $ ./myprogram || echo failure
```

These two things are sometimes called "short circuiting"

Comment: Good catch! Why don't you explain `||` also?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy: if you are in BASH or SH:

```
./c_program args...
echo "The retval is $?"
```

**Please note:** the variable `$?` contains the return value of the **last** run command.
So, you may want to store it in another variable before it changes:

```
myRet=$?
# do what you want with myRet
```

---

### Command chaining   <sup>(see [orangeoctopus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352268/orangeoctopus) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745173/get-the-status-returned-from-the-process-that-just-finished/7745205#7745205) for more info)</sup>

As you may know, a command is considered *success* if it returns 0,
while a value different than 0 indicates fome kind of *failure*.

In BASH, you can **chain commands** by using the `&&` or `||` operators:

```
command1 && command2
```

<sup>↳ In the above, `command2` will execute **only** if `command1` succedded.</sup>

```
command1 || command2
```

<sup>↳ In the above, if the first command **fails**, the second will execute.</sup>

Comment: Clarification: `$?` returns the exit status of last command in the last run pipeline: if you run `foo | bar | baz`, it gets the exit status of `baz`, while the exit statuses of `foo` and `bar` are lost.

Answer (score 1):

solution is quite simple like: `echo $?`